# Why array sort is not working in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am using sort() function of Array Library in JS. But, I am not getting correct result. Can anyone point out why?

```html
<html>
<head></head> 
<body> 
<script>

var a = [5, 17, 29, 48, 64, 21];
var c = a.sort();
alert(c);

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Why 5 is not coming in the beginning, but somewhere in middle? Can someone help?

Comment: It's sorting them as strings, not numbers

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Answer (score 0):

By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically. To sort numerically just add a new method which handles numeric sorts (sortNumber, shown below) -

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

var numArray = [5, 17, 29, 48, 64, 21];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);
alert(numArray.join(","));
```

Reference : [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

var a = [5, 17, 29, 48, 64, 21];
var c = a.sort(sortNumber);
```